# Boost + Domain Access + flushing cache

Tags: 7, caching

I have the Boost and Domain Access modules working correctly. But I've found that if the cache is flushed for one domain it doesn't clear for the others. So if content is added to one, it won't show for others until cron has been run.

Any way to fix this at all?

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Saw your post on d.o.: https://www.drupal.org/project/domain/issues/1673650

The suggested fix looks good and should still run:

```
function MODULENAME_domain_cron($domain) {
  global $base_root;
  if (isset($domain['path'])) {
    $base_root = $domain['path'];
  }
  boost_cron();
}
```

The error you have there seems strange. The argument should be passed to the hook_domain_cron method ?!?

**UPDATE:** You still can try to make the argument optional:

```
function MODULENAME_domain_cron($domain=[])
```

But I would debug that to find out the real reason ..
How does your code look for mymodule_hook_domain_cron?

Comment: I have copy pasted the same code from https://www.drupal.org/project/domain/issues/1673650

Comment: To where have you pasted that code? Do you have a module named MODULENAME??

Comment: My module name is 'mymodule' and I have pasted the code in to mymodule.module file as below:
`/*
 * Implements hook_domain_cron().
 */
function mymodule_domain_cron($domain) {
  global $base_root;
  if (isset($domain['path'])) {
    $base_root = $domain['path'];
  }
  boost_cron();
}`

Comment: I've added an update about how to make method arguments optional

Answer (score -1):

I would use use [Elysia Cron](https://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) module.

> Elysia Cron extends Drupal standard cron, allowing a fine grain control over each task and several ways to add custom cron jobs to your site.

That way I could leave regular CRON jobs just like they are (or tune them, but this is out of the scope of this question).

I would then set up Boost cron job to run every 5 minutes. There are 2 advantages to that:

1. You avoid heavy IO hit on your HDD, spreading it all over the day
2. Your original problem is pretty much solved - 5 minutes cache lag is something you probably can work with all right.